# UITextField rightView overlaps right align text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a subclass of `UITextField`. In my instance the text is right align. I have `rightView` to show money sign at the end, so when user enters data the sign for money will be always visible. I decided that this solution is better than to take text and manually add money sign after each text change.

My problem is that the text and the `rightView` slightly overlap each other. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate width according to text and font size. Use this width as max width and than arrange money sign view.

Below is method to calculate max width for text.

```
- (CGFloat) widthWithFont:(NSString *)string font:(UIFont *)font {
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
    return [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:attributes] size].width;
}
```

Comment: 10x, it works. I only have to add additional margins to the width. I also align text in the rightView right (I use label inside right view).

Comment: @new2ios Yes use same method to calculate right view label will accurate margins between two views.