# UITextField leftView and rightView overlapping issue - iOS13

Tags: ios, uikit, ios13

This is similar to [UITextField rightView overlaps right align text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653559/uitextfield-rightview-overlaps-right-align-text)
but I'm having difficulty understanding how to fix this:

[image]

The overlap happens on ios 13.1 when
I set borderStyle = .none
If border is present the text does not overlap the
image.

```
    public func addRightImage(_ image: UIImage, accessibilityIdentifier: String? = nil,
                              size: CGSize) {
        self.rightViewMode = .always
        let widthImageView : CGFloat = 25

        let rightImageView = UIImageView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthImageView, height: self.bounds.size.height))
        rightImageView.accessibilityIdentifier = accessibilityIdentifier
        rightImageView.image = image
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            self.rightView = rightImageView
        } else {
            assert(self.rightImageView == nil)
            let widthView : CGFloat = is4incher ? 30 : 50

            let rightView = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: widthView, height: self.bounds.size.height))
                       rightView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
                        self.rightView = rightView
            rightView.addSubview(rightImageView)

            rightView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            self.rightView = rightView

            rightImageView.anchors(centerX: rightView.centerXAnchor, centerY: rightView.centerYAnchor,
                                   size: size)
        }
        rightImageView.set(color: self.textColor ?? .white)
        rightImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.rightImageView = rightImageView
    }
```

if I get rid of

```
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        self.rightView = rightImageView
```

and thusly go onto the ios12 path the image is centered in the
UITextField and the text is gone altogether:
[image]

Is there anything I could do to fix my code or do I need to file a bug with apple if my code seems ok?

Comment: I have similar issue for ios13. After override `rightViewRectForBounds` methods for rightview in my custom textfiled class that's work for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 5 - iOS13**

> Prior to iOS 13, UITextField assumed that the frames of its leftView
>   and rightView were correctly set when assigned and would never change.

Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of `leftViewRect(forBounds:)` and `rightViewRect(forBounds:)` now ask the view for its `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`.

To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView, or subclass the view and implement `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`

---

Method override in textField class

```
override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: bounds.width - 50, y: 0, width: 30 , height: bounds.height)
    }
```

**Reference link -** 
https://howtotechglitz.com/apple-has-just-released-ios-13-developer-beta-5-for-iphone-ios-iphone-gadget-hacks/

Hope it's helps to you.

Answer (score 2):

Add **width** `constraint` to the `rightView`/`leftView`.

Don't forget to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

```swift
rightView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
rightView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#NeededWidth#>).isActive = true
// This is enough to make it act like before but you can set other missing constraints like height to suppress layout warnings and prevent further issues.
// rightView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: <#HeightOfTheTextField#>).isActive = true
```

You may notice some autolayout warnings in the consule because you didn't set the missing constraint for the `rightView`/`leftView`. So add missing constraints or simply ignore those.

And note that if the `rightView`/`leftView` is some kind of `StackView`, try to putting it inside a `view` and then add this view instead.

### - More Information

From the [iOS & iPadOS 13 Developer Beta 5 Release Notes](http://web.archive.org/web/20190801231842/https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios_ipados_release_notes/ios_ipados_13_beta_5_release_notes#3370268):

> UIKit - Resolved Issues
>
> Prior to iOS 13, UITextField assumed that the frames of its leftView and rightView were correctly set when assigned and would never change. Starting in iOS 13, the implementation of leftViewRect(forBounds:) and rightViewRect(forBounds:) now ask the view for its systemLayoutSizeFitting(*:). To achieve the previous behavior when linking against and running on iOS 13, add explicit sizing constraints on the view, wrap it in a plain UIView, or subclass the view and implement systemLayoutSizeFitting(*:). (51787798)

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the image which is being set to ImageView has the same size as the ImageView. This would be the simplest way to do it , just resize the image.
2. Override rightViewRect() method and provide a size as required.